# Python typing for base and concrete class (I use base class to list children but what use attributes from concrete class)

Tags: python, python-typing

Let me explain problem. I am experienced with type hints (at 90% or more) but it is hard for me - can you help?

1. I create base class with `children` attribute which have type `BaseClass`.
2. I create concrete class inheriting `BaseClass` which has `some_int` extra attribute.
3. Problem is that my type hints from `BaseClass` returns `set['BaseClass']` so children can not have extra attribute `some_int`. Whatever all children have `some_int` attribute (all will be concrete class object).

See code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class BaseClass:
    name: str
    children: set['BaseClass']

    def add_child(self, child: 'BaseClass'):
        self.children.add(child)


@dataclass
class ConcreteClass(BaseClass):
    some_int: int

    def sum(self):
        # artificial to show problem
        accumulator = 0
        for child in self.children:
            # type hint error!
            # some_int is not exists in BaseClass (what is true)
            accumulator += child.some_int
```

How to express it correctly in Python?

Comment: you can check `if isinstance(child, ConcreteClass)`, then add.

Comment: Suggestion is not related to this question. It is not need to check type but is need to write correct typing annotation.

Comment: Are you trying to express `children: set[Self]` or can `ConcreteClass` have `BaseClass` instances as children? In the former case, see [this example](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-attribute-annotations) from PEP673 (Self type), in the latter - there is no way except explicit guards `if isinstance()`, or `assert`, or `cast` (inappropriate here, IMO).

Comment: No sure what `Self` can do but in `BaseClass` `Self` should be same I think so it not solve problem. I will read PEP maybe. Remember that duck typing is in Python - I do not need override this method since it will work. I just need override only typing :)

Comment: Duck typing mean I do need to check if duck is duck if behave like duck.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need instances of `ConcreteClass` accessing that attribute, you can overwrite the type hint of the `children` set:

```py
@dataclass
class ConcreteClass(BaseClass):
    some_int: int
    children: set['ConcreteClass']
```

This means that `ConcreteClass.children` can only ever contain itself, which allows the type checker to determine that all elements of the set must have `some_int`.

If you want to have more than just one `ConcreteClass`, you still need to tell the type checker what it can be sure about. You can either do this by defining that `BaseClass` also has the attribute `some_int` or by using a [Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol). Protocols allow you to introduce duck typing to the type checker - it can use the Protocol to check if any class exposes the correct attributes/methods, no matter what they inherit from.

```py
from typing import Protocol

class HasInt(Protocol):
    some_int: int
    def some_method(self, arg: int) -> int:
        ...

@dataclass
class BaseClass:
    name: str
    children: set[HasInt]
```

This tells the type checker that all children have to follow the `HasInt` protocol. The type checker can now allow any instance, even of unrelated classes, to be used in `children` as long as they all have a some_int attribute and the `some_method` method which matches the signature defined in the Protocol.

Comment: It looks like solution ... let's check it.

Comment: It works for class attributes but not for methods. No idea how to do for method.

Comment: I've linked the docs on Protocol which show how to do it for methods. tl;dr: define the method normally but leave the content empty save for a ...

Comment: I create Generics for it I will check Protocol. Let me think about it.